# Starting multiple remote servers with Akka

Tags: remoting, akka

I'm running into some deployment issues using Akka remoting to implement a small search application.

I want to deploy my ActorSystem on a set of local cluster machines to use them as workers, but I'm a bit confused for what to put into my application.conf to make this happen.  For example, I can use:

```
akka.remote {
  transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
  netty {
    hostname = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 2552
  }
}
```

Each worker just runs the ActorSystem at startup.

This allows my worker machines to bind to their address when they start up, but then they refuse to listen to messages:

`beaker-24: [ERROR] ... dropping message DaemonMsgWatch for non-local recipient akka://SearchService@beaker-24:2552/remote at akka://SearchService@0.0.0.0:2552`

The documentation I've found for this so far only discusses deployment on my localhost, which is not so useful :).  I'm hoping there is a way to do this without generating a separate configuration for each host.

---

Update:

Using an empty string as the hostname allows for contacting the host via the normal IP address.  Addressing using the hostname itself doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: Could be a bug, please open a ticket!

Comment: Thanks, I will try to codify the expected behavior and submit something.  I found using an empty string as an address works in the meantime (I should have read through the configuration reference a bit more thoroughly!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting “0.0.0.0” as host name will currently basically disable remoting, because that is not a legal IP to send to. Background: actor references get the configured IP (or host name) inserted in their address part when they leave the local system, and that is exactly their “pointer home” for other systems to send messages back.

There has been an effort by Scott which would enable a system to receive replies to a different address [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/396), but that is not included yet—and we may well chose a different solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks -  I ended up with a solution for my case- if I leave the host field empty, it binds to the "any" address, but I can still access the host by it's IP address (unfortunately, the host doesn't recognize it's hostname as a valid receiver address).

Still, it's working!